# Fetching images synchronously using javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, fetch

I have an app that generated links to images that have been downloaded.

When I use this code on its own (as in a single uri) it works for what I am wanting to achieve, the image path is dynamically created and the local image is created and I can stored it and reference it elsewhere where I need.

```
var path = getOS() + '' + object.link + '/' + object.icon
var outside
fetch(path)
   .then(response => response.blob())
   .then(images => {
   outside = URL.createObjectURL(images)  
   localStorage.setItem('stored_img'+ _object.link, outside)
})
```

The problem is when I try and loop through several images and try to create localStorage links to them. All of the local Storageitems are undefined or null

I suspect that the code is executing before the localstorage is saved.
I do not know how to apply the working code to synchronous fetch.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've posted the code that doesn't work. You're looping through local storage before it's saved, but we can't see that code here.

Comment: `I suspect that the code is executing before the localstorage is saved.` unclear what that means with what was provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a map of all requests and use `Promise.all` to resolve their URLs.

Let's say you have a list of URLs:

```js
const urls = ['url1', 'url2', ...];
```

Create a map of fetch requests like this:

```js
const requests = urls.map((url) => fetch(url).then(resp => resp.blob()));
```

Now pass this request map to `Promise.all`:

```js
Promise.all(requests).then(responseArr => {
  const imagesArr = responseArr.map(image => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(image);
    localStorage.setItem('...', url);
    return url;
  });
  // now you have a list of image urls in imagesArr which you can use. They are also stored in localStorage
});
```